# angularjs '@' local scope property not doing binding

Tags: angularjs

I'm using asp.net mvc4 with angularjs and I'm facing a problem while using a directive with an isolated  scope.

This is what I've done in js file:-

```
.controller('myTransactionController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.debt = 100;

}])
.directive('myDebt', function () {
   function link(scope, element, attr) {
    element.text(scope.debtval);
}
return {
    scope: { debtval: '@mydebtval' },
    link: link
}
});
```

and this is in view

```
<input name="name" data-ng-model="debt" />

<span my-debt mydebtval="{{debt}}" >{{debt}}</span>
```

As far as '@' local scope is considered, it's one-way binding property and it should change
as value of its parent changed but as i change value of input type(i.e. parent scope value) the value of span tag doesn't change.

Can anyone tell why span tag value doesn't change when i change value of input tag?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
scope: { debtval: '@myDebtVal' }
```

And using it like this:

```
<span my-debt my-debt-val="{{debt}}" >
```

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4Ly5bw3d/1/)

Bare in mind that there is a naming convention that needs to be followed when you want to access the attributes of your directive. Your directive is called 'myDeb', so its attributes should be named like this 'myDebXxxYyy' using  the same camel-case expansion as the directive names themselves do.

Another thing that you may want to know is that you could have done this:

```
scope: { val: '@' }
```

and then used it just like you did before:

```
<span my-debt my-debt-val="{{debt}}" >
```

and the name of the scope would be `$scope.val` instead of `$scope.debtval`, of course.

Comment: @user2456467 I just updated my answer, hopefully this will help you understand why. I will make another update in a sec explaining a few more tricks that you can use with the names of your directive attributes. ;)

Comment: @user2456467 Please let me know if this solved your question, thanks!

Comment: Ooops!! just realised making attribute follow camel-case makes here fails it. In simple words its not working with attribute name '@myDebtVal' but yes it works with '@mydebtval'

Comment: @user2456467 it does work! Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/4Ly5bw3d/ your problem must be something else.

Comment: Also one more thing it works fine with '@myDebtval', please note small v here.

Comment: It does work, check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/4Ly5bw3d/1/ Please make sure that you are following the naming conventions that I've given you, also make sure that you understand the explanation of my answer. Thanks!